# 422 Error returned correctly in Postman but not in Angular 8 HTTPClient Post Request

Tags: angular, http, postman, http-status-code-422

I'm testing a simple Login API Call in Angular 8.  When I use the correct credentials the post works fine and I'm logged in.

When I test the call with invalid credentials, I'm not seeing the correct error response in Angular.

When I test the call in Postman with the invalid credentials I get:

```
{ "error": { "title": "Error", "status": 422, "message": "Those details are incorrect", "code": "VALIDATION_ERROR" } }
```

When I make the call in Angular with the invalid credentials I get this:

```
Error Response:  {
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null,
        "headers": {}
    },
    "status": 422,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "https://myServerName/login",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for https://myServerName/login: 422 OK",
    "error": null
}
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because when you get the error response from API, then content type in the response header is not "application/json". So angular, not able to parse the error response correctly.

Comment: The content type in the response header IS set to "application/json". This is what I see in Postman against the headers: Cache-Control →no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
Cache-Control →post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →158
Content-Type →application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date →Fri, 26 Jul 2019 08:59:29 GMT
Expires →Mon, 26 Jul 1990 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified →Fri, 26 Jul 2019 08:59:29 GMT
Pragma →no-cache
Server →nginx

Comment: please match the same header in your browser(google chrome) network tab.